# What have I done wrong in my code? It shows an Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript

My code shows an Unexpected token error with a closing parenthesis ). What does it mean?

I've tried adding and taking away parenthesis and curly brackets.

```
const getUserChoice = userInput => {userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
if(userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors') {
    return userInput;
} else {
  console.log('Error! That\'s not part of the game!');
}
```

It should not log anything, instead it logs an error.

Comment: properly input your code and you will see why

Comment: There is a missing curly brace at the end. Consider using a [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)).

Comment: Please use editor/IDE with JS syntax highlighting or linter/checker that verifies syntax in your source files before execution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your code. You have forget to add the missing end (`}`) curly brace.

You have used:

```
const getUserChoice = userInput => {userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
```

instead of:

```
const getUserChoice = userInput => {userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();}
```

Could you see the missing curly brace in the `you haved used` example?

**Hint:** follow @grumbler_chester suggestion. Use a Code-Editor or an IDE for syntax highlighting.

Comment: I tried that and it gave me an error that said userInput is not defined

Comment: @FireFlyCrisis you will find often code has multiple errors and you have to fix one to reach the other.  This answer is correct.  userInput being undefined is another problem you will have to solve - it was not seen until the first error was corrected because the interpreter could not parse the code.

Comment: @FireFlyCrisis please dont delete or change your comment. As paul said: when developing software you will get often errors. Keep in mind: this is a normal process (try error) for your whole life as developer.

Comment: I believe I fixed the problem, I added another line and put a curly bracket at the end, it did not show an error. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @FireFlyCrisis but did you get our message? what does it mean to be a developer and how to deal with comments in stackoverflow?